# Get "operator does not exist" when update an enum in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm using postgresql 9.6 and nestjs with typeorm. I want to update an enum and all columns that are using that enum.

Here is my enum

```
export enum DocumentStatus {

Draft = 'Draft',

Published = 'Published',

Archived = 'Archived',

Withdrawn = 'Withdrawn'

}
```

Here is my Status model

```
class Status {

@Column({

type: 'enum',

enum: Status,

enumName: 'current_state',

nullable: false

})

currentState: Status;
}
```

When I update entity model and generate a migration file by typeorm, it has the code below in the migration file

```
await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TYPE "public"."current_state" RENAME TO "current_state_old"`);

await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TYPE "public"."current_state" AS ENUM('Draft', 'Published', 'Archived', 'Withdrawn', 'NotPublished', 'Migrated')`);

await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "status_transitions" ALTER COLUMN "current_state" TYPE "public"."current_state" USING "current_state"::"text"::"public"."current_state"`);

await queryRunner.query(`DROP TYPE "public"."current_state_old"`);
```

This is the error I got, the problem came from the third command, I can't set the new enum to current_state column. Anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: current_state = current_state_old
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 199
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce that, it works for me. But why do you create a new type instead of adding new values with `ALTER TYPE ... ADD VALUE`?